# Know better (with somebody) idiom?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Days ago I came across this idiom "know better" and I found out that this could be used with "than that / than to do sth", but I recently found this sentence with this expression followed by "with". Do you usually use this supposed idiom with "with" when it is followed by a name? I found this sentence in the book "39 clues - The maze of bones"

> If it had been anybody else, Dan would've hit back, but he knew better
>   with the Holts.

Comment: It means *If it had been anybody else, Dan would've hit back, But he knew better [than to fight] with the Holts.*

Comment: @Matt, that's very well put - you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 5):

In context, the sentence means

> *If it had been anybody else, Dan would've hit back, But he knew better [than to fight] with the Holts*.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different cases that I know where "know better" will pop up:

- ["When you know better, you do better"](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/9821-when-you-know-better-you-do-better) from Maya Angelou that I've heard Oprah repeat more than a few times would be an inspirational quote.
- "Bob likes to bluff but he knew better with Dean" - In this case the point is that there is some previous action that may be handled differently given the presence of a person.  In the case of the example you give, there is an implication about "hitting back" that one could infer.
- "You know better than that!" being what someone may say when someone performs some childish action that the remark is intended as a negative comment.